# Use Sharepoint to create an editable internal divisional phone list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, custom-list, excel

I would like to create an internal phone list for our division.  The idea is to have it available on our Sharepoint site and make divisional team leaders responsible for keeping their team information up to date.

I'm thinking an Excel file but would appreciate advice on the most efficient way to do this. And if anyone has already done, has it worked well?

TIA

Cheers
Tracy

Comment: Please explain more clearly so that someone can help you with the solution. please give more information about requirement and implementation

Comment: Hi Raghavendra   With my limited knowledge of Sharepoint 2013 I will try.  The list needs to be a centrally accessible collection of individual contact details that can be edited by the team leaders or individuals.  We're just trying to create a central phone directory that can easily be kept updated and this is how the Exec wants to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the **Contacts List** which is present out-of-box in SharePoint you can add this list by Navigating to **Site Contents** and then click **Add an app**, Search for **Contacts** as in image below

[image]

It will give you a list where you can add all the contacts details for any person in your division. (you can use the columns as per your needs)  To make sure this located centrally, you can place it in root site collection(if not for multiple site collections)

To make sure that only restricted people access it you will have to break list's default permission and provide permission to only those users or groups who would be responsible for managing the contacts in list

Comment: Your welcome can you accept it as answer